# How to delete uploaded image from directory folder in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I want to delete the image not only in database, but in folder too.

This is my database table:

```
group_id
group_name
group_descrtion
group_picture
```

This is my controller :

```
    public function delete_group()
    {
            $group_id = $this->input->post('group_id');
            $group_picture = $this->input->post('group_picture');

            $this->group_model->delete_group($group_id, $group_picture);
            redirect('product_group');
    }
```

this is my model :

```
        function delete_group($group_id, $group_picture)
        {
                $this->db->where('group_id', $group_id);

                unlink(base_url("uploads/".$group_picture));

                $this->db->delete('product_group', array('group_id' => $group_id));
        }
```

and this is my view :

```
 <?=form_open_multipart('product_group/delete_group');?>

   <input type="hidden" class="form-control" placeholder="Group ID" name="group_id">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Group ID" name="group_picture">

  <div class="modal-footer">
     <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
     <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
 </form>
```

I succeed in deleting the data in the database, but the image in the folder are not also be deleted.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
unlink(base_url("uploads/".$group_picture));
```

Should be

```
unlink("uploads/".$group_picture);
```

You need the path, not the url.

Comment: Thank you, everything going well :)

Answer (score 3):

Use CI constant `FCPATH` as location of root directory, so in your case that should be:

```
unlink( FCPATH . "uploads/" . $group_picture );
```

Notice that `FCPATH` already has trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

To delete a file/picture you can use `delete_files()` function. First load the file helper and then pass the file path as a first parameter in the `delete_files()` function and `true` as the second.like-

```
delete_files($path, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

USE FCPATH in you Delete function

```
unlink(FCPATH."uploads/".$image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give only **directory** name that starts from the **folder**, not from **base_url**

unlink("uploads/group/Images/".$group_picture);